# Jquery date picker in popup window

Tags: jquery, datepicker, popup

I'm using bpopup to manage my popup window and that works well.

However I've hit an issue when I want to add a datepicker to the popup.

In my parent page I'm loading jquery-ui, jquery and my js file.

My js file has :

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()
```

and in my popup window I have added :

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
```

When I click this nothing happens.. no errors are shown in the console.

If I move that code to my parent I get the date picker as expected.

I'm trying to work out why it isn't working in my popup..

My popup is opened with :

```
$("#open").click(function() {
    $('#pop_up').bPopup({
            loadUrl: 'page.php',
    });
  });
```

can anyone advise why the date picker isn't working ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I can get it working if I use :

```
$("body").on('click', '#datepicker', function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

But then it requires multiple clicks in the field to enable, and then use it.

Is this due to the #datepicker element not being available when the Jquery loads ?

How do I get around that ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using HTML5's Date input type? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: I didn't think it was supported by IE ?

Comment: I can't remember if it is supported or not, and if it isn't, it never will be supported because of Edge.  But IE usage is dropping (https://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-january-2016-12-month-review/). If you choose to still support it, that's your choice, but just so you know this input type exists and is more reliable than jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the datepicker working in my popup using:

```
$("body").on('focus', '#datepicker', function(){
        $( this ).datepicker();     
    });
```

That works fine.